# cross tab column from right to left in crystal report visual studio 2012 asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I am using crystal report with visual studio 2012 asp.net.I want to make a following design using cross tab.Rows show on right side and columns moves from right to left.Crosstab start from right side.I did not find any direction setting in cross tab.How can i achieve following design using cross tab

[image]

Comment: unfortunately I don't think SAP supports RTL crosstab reports, as indicated by them here: http://scn.sap.com/thread/3408797 . I think your only option is to create a manual crosstab or doing the heavy lifting of the data formatting in a database stored procedure. (In other words, write a stored procedure which formats the data in a RTL cross tab format). Sorry

Comment: @DouglasTimms hi, after 5 years is Crystal Report still doesn't support right to left with crosstab reports?